# php laravel i have a problem in composer when install or remove packages or write any command for composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

PHP laravel I have a problem in composer when installing or remove packages or writing any command for the composer

[image]

Comment: try composer dump-autoload and try again

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Can you try running `php artisan package:discover --ansi` directly and see what happens?

Comment: @ceejayoz the command "php artisan package:discover --ansi" runnig but when run any composer command I have the error

Answer (score 0):

- first of all your composer command should be `composer remove laravel/telescope` instead of `vendor/telescope`.
- you should rename this file from `app/Models/Service_old.php` to `app/Models/Service.php`, if there is another file in the same directory with the same `Service.php` name, then move the old one (or change its extension) somewhere else so it will not be auto detected by composer.
- at last, while the package discovery issue is not provided in the screenshot, you may run the following commands and see how things went after:

```
composer clear-cache
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your `storage/` & `bootstrap/cache` directory writable.

Make sure your `.env` file doesn't contain any spaces.

Ex: `key=value` instead of `key=va lue`

remove the `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file. then

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Try to remove `/bootstrap/compiled.php` ( if you have it )

most likely the problem is with caching as all what we do here is remove the cached files

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Which of these steps helps to resolve the given error, and why?

Comment: @NicoHaase you can easily see it's deleting cache files!

Comment: What do you mean by that? Changing anything in the `.env` file does not delete any cache file. Also, add all explanation to your answer by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase and the line after that? and the last line? you just didn't read the whole thing. the `.env` line is extra

Comment: Feel free to add **all** clarification to your answer by editing it. This helps others to learn from your answer

Comment: will redo the answer again!